# Verifying that workers put in the right amount of hours at work

Tags: word-request

I'm developing an application for remote workers to be able to check in and out of work and I've stumbled upon a concept I don't know how to translate into worker.

A worker's manager is supposed to verify that each worker is putting in the correct amount of hours, to make sure that no one is slacking off. In Spanish we'd call this "control of hours" or "hourly control", but I've never come across a similar concept in English. Could you tell me of any similar concepts?

Thank you!

Comment: I would say I fill in a timesheet and submit it to my manager for verification.  So I suppose "timesheet verification", but that's not a particularly well-known idiom as far as I know.

Comment: I would clarify that I'm not looking for an exact idiom - such an idiom may not be commonplace or even exist for all I know. As far as it's understandable and clearly conveys what it's meant to be, it's more than good enough. So thank you! :)

Comment: What is the actual term in Spanish?

Comment: I would say "control de horas" or "control horario".